# How to convert OracleBlob to string

Tags: vb.net, oracle, blob

I have an oracleblob retrieved from a store procedure. My type is a `OracleBlob`

I'm not sure how to convert this blob to byte then string. It does not allow direct casting. I'm not using execute reader therefore I cant read from a stream. Is there explicit ways to transform a blob to byte then string. Are a straight forward way to to this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple really... apparently downvoter didn't know.

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataBaseSource").ToString()).ToString())
Dim command As New OracleCommand
Dim htmlBlobReturn As New OracleParameter("pCERTIFICATE_FILE_FRA", OracleDbType.Blob)
htmlBlobReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
command.Parameters.Add(htmlBlobReturn)
Dim fTemp As OracleBlob = htmlBlobReturn.Value
Dim ftLen As Integer = fTemp.Length
Dim footer(ftLen - 1) As Byte
fTemp.Read(footer, 0, ftLen)
Dim html = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(footer)
```

output is `html` and is in the same string value as inserted.